# Android: how do I launch DatePickerDialog with onFocusChangeListener?

Tags: android, datepickerdialog, onfocuschangelistener

I have an `EditText` line on a user input form.  A click on the EditText to launch a DatePickerDialog is working fine using a `setOnTouchListener`.  The `setonFocusChangeListener` I set up to handle an `OnFocusChange` onto the EditText is not working.  What am I missing here?

(Not sure if this helps but in an earlier version I used a `DatePickerFragment` and the `onFocusChange` works fine...so maybe the issue is using a `DatePickerDialog` rather than a Fragment?  The two lines I used to launch the Fragment with the `onFocusChange()` were:

```
DatePickerFragment newFragment = new DatePickerFragment(); // and
newFragment.show(getSupportFragmentManager(), "datePicker");)
```

Activity.java

```
public class Activity extends AppCompatActivity implements OnFocusChangeListener {
    ...
    private DatePickerDialog zDatePickerDialog
    private int mYear;
    private int mMonth;
    private int mDay;

    Override
    protected void onCreate(final Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        zListenerEditText = (ListenerEditText) findViewById(id.ZEditText);

        Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
        mYear = calendar.get(Calendar.YEAR);
        mMonth = calendar.get(Calendar.MONTH);
        mDay = calendar.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH);
        mDatePickerDialog = new DatePickerDialog(this,this,mYear,mMonth,mDay);

        // This is working fine to handle the a click to launch the DatePickerDialog
        zListenerEditText.setOnTouchListener(new View.OnTouchListener() {
            @Override
            public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
                // launch the DatePickerDialog.
                mDatePickerDialog.show();        
                return true;
            }
        }); 

        // This does not work to launch the DatePickerDialog
        zListenerEditText.setOnFocusChangeListener(new View.OnFocusChangeListener() {
        @Override
        public void onFocusChange(View v, boolean hasFocus) {    
            if (hasFocus ) {
                // launch the DatePickerDialog.
                mDatePickerDialog.show();
        ...
        });  
    }    
}
```

activity.xml

```
    ...
    <com.widget.ListenerEditText
        android:id="@+id/ZEditText"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"        
        android:inputType="none"
        android:textColor="#FFFFFF"  />
```

Edit 1 in Activity file:

```
...
@Override
public void onFocusChange(View v, boolean hasFocus) {
    switch (v.getId()) {
        case id.CEditText:
            Toast.makeText(this,"C",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            // Handle onFocusChange for editText1
            break;
        case id.DEditText:
            Toast.makeText(this,"D",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            // Handle onFocusChange for editText2
            break;
        case id.EEditText:
            Toast.makeText(this,"E",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            // Handle onFocusChange for editText3
            break;
        case id.FEditText:
            Toast.makeText(this,"F",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            // Handle onFocusChange for editText4
            break;
        case id.GEditText:
            Toast.makeText(this,"G",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            // Handle default scenario.
            break;
    }
}
```

Comment: remove implements onFocusChangeListener and check if you are getting toast

Comment: yes I get the Toast when the Activity UI loads.

Comment: So now DatePickerDialog should also load, give it a try!!

Comment: How?  I removed the onFocusChange code that launches the Dialog and I also removed the onTouch code so there is no code remaining launch the Dialog.

Comment: check the answer provided if its working

Answer (score 2):

Remove OnFocusChangeListener from here `public class Activity extends AppCompatActivity implements OnFocusChangeListener`

keep it like this

```
public class Activity extends AppCompatActivity {
zListenerEditText = (ListenerEditText) findViewById(id.ZEditText);

        Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
        mYear = calendar.get(Calendar.YEAR);
        mMonth = calendar.get(Calendar.MONTH);
        mDay = calendar.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH);
        mDatePickerDialog = new DatePickerDialog(this,this,mYear,mMonth,mDay);

        // This is working fine to handle the a click to launch the DatePickerDialog

        // This does not work to launch the DatePickerDialog
        zListenerEditText.setOnFocusChangeListener(new View.OnFocusChangeListener() {
        @Override
        public void onFocusChange(View v, boolean hasFocus) {    
            if (hasFocus ) {
                // launch the DatePickerDialog.
                mDatePickerDialog.show();
        ...
        });  
}
```

Answer (score 1):

This happens because your onFocusChange event is never gets fired as it's been consumed by your onTouch event as you are returning true. You can't have both the events. If you just want to show a dialog on focus then I think listening for onFocusChange only will do the job.

EDIT: 1

How could I miss that? As @mrinmoy mentioned you should remove implements onFocusChange from `public class Activity extends AppCompatActivity implements OnFocusChangeListener`.

The problem is that you are listening for focus change twice. When you `implements OnFocusChangeListener` all your focus change related to entire activity are listened inside your global `onFocusChange()` method on your activity that you've overridden. So in this case your onFocusChange that you've set on your edittext will never gets called.

So if you want to handle focusChange for multiple edittext then implements onFocusChange is good, otherwise setting it on individual edittext is better.

In case if you want to handle onFocusChange on multiple editexts then here is the sample.

remove onFocusChange listeners from individual editexts.

handle your global `onFocusChange()` method like below.

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements View.OnFocusChangeListener{
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        ....
    }

    @Override
    public void onFocusChange(View v, boolean hasFocus) {
        switch (v.getId()) {
            case R.id.editText1:
                // Handle onFocusChange for editText1
                break;
            case R.id.editText2:
                // Handle onFocusChange for editText2
                break;
            case R.id.editText3:
                // Handle onFocusChange for editText3
                break;
            case R.id.editText4:
                // Handle onFocusChange for editText4
                break;
            default:
                // Handle default scenario.
                break;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Interesting.  I removed all of the onTouch() code and the DatePickerDialog still does not launch when focus moves to the EditText line.  Any thoughts?

Comment: Seems weird. Can you check for whether your onFocusChange is actually getting called or not. So we come to know whether the problem is with your listener or dialog.

Comment: I added a Toast to the onFocusChange() and it is not firing so my guess is that onFocusChange is not getting called.  Android newbie here so not sure how to test any other way.

Comment: I use setOnFocusChangeListener() on multiple EditTexts.  So not sure how to fix.

Comment: Ok so if I understand, you suggest to set up one global onFocusChangeListener and then apply it against each EdtiText individually using the case code which should work well since focus can only ever be on one EditText at a time?

Comment: Yes, exactly. You can do this for any other view as well e.g button. It is efficient to do this instead setting multiple listeners.

Comment: Very good.  I will go to work on that and give it a try.  I will check back for answer acceptance and upvote.  Cheers.

Comment: when I use the EditText variables that reference (for example, "case id.FEditText:") that references the id name in the xml file nothing happens when I run the app.  Since the View.Listener is on a View shouldn't I be using this "case.id.fListenerEditText:" because that is the ListenerEditText in the Activity that references findViewById(id.FEditText)?   If yes, my problem is that fListenerEditText is not accessible with R.id.outside of onCreate().

Comment: No it's a different method. how it can be inside onCreate()? you have to use like R.id.theIdYouGivenInYourXML with **android:id="@+id/myId**

Answer (score 0):

Try this one, it is working for me

```
 inputDOB.setOnFocusChangeListener(new View.OnFocusChangeListener() {
        @Override
        public void onFocusChange(View view, boolean b) {
            if (b) {
                 datePicker();
            }
        }
    });
```

and the **datePicker** method is

```
 public void datePicker() {
    final Calendar c = Calendar.getInstance();
    mYear = c.get(Calendar.YEAR);
    mMonth = c.get(Calendar.MONTH);
    mDay = c.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH);
        datePickerDialog = new DatePickerDialog(this,
            new DatePickerDialog.OnDateSetListener() {
                @Override
                public void onDateSet(DatePicker view, int year,
                                      int monthOfYear, int dayOfMonth) {
                    inputDOB.setText(formatDate(year,monthOfYear+1,dayOfMonth));
                     datePickerDialog.dismiss();
                    hideSoftKeyboard(SignUpActivity.this);
                }
            }, mYear, mMonth, mDay);
    datePickerDialog.getDatePicker().setMaxDate(System.currentTimeMillis());
    datePickerDialog.show();
}
```